# How can I get content of HTML <body>

Tags: java, html, dom

when I have html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 text
  <div>
  text2
    <div>
    text3
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

how can I get with DOM parser in JAVA content of body: 
`text
 <div>
  text2
    <div>
    text3
    </div>
  </div>`
becasuse method getTextContent return:text text2 text3. - so without tags.

It is possible with SAX, but it is possible with DOM, too?

Comment: What DOM parser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The `getTextContent` is behaving as I would expect - getting the textural content of the HTML fragment. Can you check the API docs for the DOM parser and see if there's a similar method with a name like `getHtmlContent`?

Comment: I agree; you can treat the entire thing as String and using String.indexOf(..) method subString(..) everything in the body tag.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to parse the document into a DOM and serialise only the portion of the DOM you wanted. Using the DOM Level 3 LS interfaces you can [serialise](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializer.html) the outer-XML of a single node with:

```
LSSerializer serializer= implementation.createLSSerializer();
String html= serializer.writeToString(node);
```

To get the inner-XML you would need to `writeToString` each child node in turn (eg. into a `StringBuffer`).

Depending on what DOM implementation you are using there may be alternative non-standard methods. There may also be risks with serialising HTML as XML, if that's what you're doing... eg. a standard XML serialiser may output a self-closing tag for an empty tag, which can confuse browsers parsing the output as legacy-HTML.

Comment: @schwiz: an implementation of the DOM Level 3 DOMImplementationLS interface. You'd traditionally get one from `document.implementation` (`getImplementation` in Java bindings).

Comment: document.getImplementation returns an abstract implementation that does not include createLSSerializer. Any tips? I am using the DOM level 3 library included with Android. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Document.html

Comment: @schwiz: typically you can cast the DOMImplementation to a `(DOMImplementationLS)`. In some bindings you might have to call `implementation.getFeature("LS", "3.0")`.